# Wordpress: custom paged query

Tags: wordpress

I used to use this query with wordpress to get my post types paged

```
  <?php 
      $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $args = array(
                     'post_type' => 'post',
                     'posts_per_page' => -1,
                     'paged' => $paged,
                     'author' => $user_id
                  );
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

      if($my_query->have_posts()):
          while($my_query->have_posts()):$my_query->the_post();

    ?>
      <article class="listaNoticia column large-6 medium-6 small-12">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <p class="data"><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></p> <br><br>
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </a>
      </article>
      <!-- END ITEM -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


<div class="paginacao column large-12 medium-12 snall-12">
      <div>
        <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
        <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) { wp_paginate(); } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I used to use this query, but now its loading all the posts and no pagination.

Someone getting this problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you get it working before, but `'posts_per_page' => -1` is supposed to disable pagination. Try left it unset or use the value you wanted.

Answer (score -2):

- In Dashboard -> Setting -> Reading, how many blog pages show at most you setting to show? 10? You should be set 'posts_per_page' the same as.
  Or you can try this code:

```html
<?php

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
 'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
 'format' => '?paged=%#%',
 'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
 'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```